# Java Robot Keypress Command Key

Tags: java, macos, keyboard, awtrobot

What is the VK_[key] code for the command key on a mac, if one exists? I am trying to get a Robot (java Robot) to press the command key. I am using the command keyPress(), and I need to know the integer keycode for the command key on a mac.

Comment: I believe you're after KeyEvent.VK_META, but you will need to test it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`KeyEvent.VK_META`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_META), with key code `157`, is Java's virtual key that maps to the the Mac command key.

Comment: Is this still working for you? For me this is sadly not working.

Comment: @lony Do you have simple example code I can run to test whether it's working or not? I could write my own test but if you have something that could save me the time that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem for me was that I needed a delay in between this and the other key selects. Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

[KeyEvent.VK_META](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_META) can be used as COMMAND button in Mac OS.

if its not working with you, that is because you need to add a delay

sample code for opening a new tab

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
robot.delay(200);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is also `isMetaDown()` method, which in my case works if somebody wants to use the shortcuts for copy/paste text and so on.

Sample code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.isMetaDown() && (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_V) && readonly.isSelected()){
        e.consume();
    }
}
```